# How to view values of system columns in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

There are a few columns that are defined by Postgres for its use (i.e. tableoid, cmax, xmax, cmin, xmin, ctid) that I would like to view the values of.

I tried running the following query in the query tool:

```
SELECT * FROM public."MyTable"
```

but it only returns my user-generated columns and nothing else.

I can see these columns exist when I expand the Table>Columns list but I can't find an option to enable viewing their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the columns to your select statement like

```
select tableoid,cmax, xmax, cmin, xmin, ctid, * from public."MyTable";
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much :)